# How can i convert "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000" to date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a string like 2009-10-09 08:39:20 +0000 and want to covert into an exact date format. Can anyone help me?

The date format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000" (I don't know the meaning of +0000)

Comment: This is not duplicate question my main thing is how i convert this date to perfectly this formate like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000" (i dont know the exactly meaning of +0000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter` like this

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate* tDate = [df dateFromString:@"2009-10-09 08:39:20 +0000"];
```

Comment: It is not working for me the tDate is nil when i debug for getting the date

Comment: @SmarterSusheel i edited the answer in `setDateFromat` line. check it out

Comment: Ya done but what is the meaning of +0000?

Comment: ya jecky i think you are right. ZZZ is something like UTC formate